# Is there any possibility to add a username and password login to my Stack Overflow account?

Tags: feature-request, login, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I read some other answers where they said that if you used Google to create your account, you can only use Google to log in.

But there might be instances where we might want to log in on other machines, possibly external PCs.

In such situations, it might not be safe to log in to your Gmail just to access any Stack Exchange accounts.

Hence, can anyone tell me if I can add a username / password login to my account?

If not, can I request this as a feature from the Stack Exchange community?